# Pandas, groupby, rolling STD

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to calculate a grouped `rolling_std`for a series of data and keep getting a value error `cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`. I think from basic googling it's referring to the fact that `trip_id` are a series of duplicates, but I've grouped and applied functions using this same dataset before, so I can't understand why it works in some respects and not in others. Both functions work on their own.

Hoping SO can educate me.

Code:

`df['std'] = df.groupby('trip_id')['knots'].apply(pd.rolling_std,2,min_periods=1)`

DF:

```
                     trip_id     knots
time                                  
2016-01-03 23:42:20    18526  0.233261
2016-01-03 23:43:16    18526  8.572334
2016-01-03 23:43:15    18527  0.252699
2016-01-03 23:42:49    18528  6.434110
2016-01-03 23:42:48    18528  0.719221
```

Comment: When I run the code you provided on the data above, it works! pandas 0.11.0

Comment: Interesting, I'm using `pd 0.17.1` `dtypes = trip_id - int64` & `knots - float64, index = datetime64` If I reindex, the code above works. Any thoughts why?